# Using a @JmsListener to handle sendAndReceive and just send

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I have a spring service that has @JmsListener method. It gets invoked by a client send out a message via JmsMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(). This works fine.

```
@Service
public class JmsMessageProcessor {
    @JmsListener(destination = "myDestination")
    protected Message<MyResponseObj> handleRequest(final MyInputObj myObj) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(processObj(myObj)).build();
    }

}
```

.

```
// client
 MyResponseObj response = jmsMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(myDestination, myObj,
                MyResponseObj.class);
```

I'm attemptign to implement on the client, functionality for just doing a `convertSend` call. That is, the client will send and forget, and not wait for a response. I have made such a call, and it does get processed on the server side

```
 jmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(myDestination, myObj);
```

But, I get an error on the server side indicating that the request message does not contain a reply-to destination. This makes some sense to me, because i'm not doing a "receive" method call via the jmsMessageTemplate. But, I'm not sure what to do about this. Is it possible to have another JmsListener method for the same destination, but handle specificaly the "send without reply" requests, or do i have to create a seperate destination and JMS queue? Basically, I want my server / jms listener to be able to not send back a response if it doesn't need to.

```
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot determine response destination: Request message does not contain reply-to destination, and no default response destination set.
org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ReplyFailureException: Failed to send reply with payload [GenericMessage [payload=MyResponseObj@51c082ec, headers={timestamp=1462996638601, id=41877e45-b220-a320-f07a-64f9d50d98ae}]]; nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot determine response destination: Request message does not contain reply-to destination, and no default response destination set.
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.handleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:249) ~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:68) ~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:721) ~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:681) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:315) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:253) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1150) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1039) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_99]
Caused by: javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot determine response destination: Request message does not contain reply-to destination, and no default response destination set.
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.getResponseDestination(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:343) ~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.getResponseDestination(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:316) ~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.handleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:245) ~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use two `@JmsListener`s and the `selector` property to direct the different message types to each listener.

This requires the sender to set a message property that is then used in the selector expression.

It's a bit more complicated when using the messaging template because you have to build a new message but with the basic `JmsTemplate`:

```
jmsTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(dest, object, messagePostProcessor);
```

where `messagePostProcessor` has a method

```
public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) {
    message.setStringProperty("requiresReply", "yes");
    return message;
}
```

Then use `requiresReply=yes/no` in the selector.

If you want to avoid the cast and use the messaging template, you need to use `MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader(...).build()` in the (different) `MessagePostProcessor`). In this case it's a spring-messaging `Message` not a JMS `Message`.

**EDIT**

You really don't need any of this, though, if your listener can tell from the data whether a reply is expected and simply returns `null` for messages that don't need a reply.

Comment: OK, I looked at MessagePostProcessor, but I thought it was a method of receiving a response ascynhronously. The MessagePostProcessor will execute prior to the send, by JMS? This seems promising.

Comment: Yes; it's a mechanism allowing you to modify the JMS Message created by the conversion, before it is sent to JMS.

Comment: OK, it looks like the convertSendAndReceive you specified doesn't exist. I think I need to specify the target class type.

Comment: I created a new org.springframework.messaging.core.MessagePostProcessor, but there is no method named setStringProperty on org.springframework.messaging.Message

Comment: Please read the answer more carefully - there are two different callbacks depending on whether you are using a `JmsTemplate` or a `JmsMessagingTemplate`. The older `JmsTemplate` doesn't support generics so you have to cast the reply but in this case it would be more efficient because you would avoid the intermediate spring-messaging `Message`.

Comment: OK, so since I'm using JmsMessageTemplate, it seems like I can do the following. Do you agree?

return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).
                                    setHeader("requiresReply", "false").build();


Also, I want to use convertAndSend, not convertSendAndReceive.

Comment: For the message you expect replies to, you will use `convertSendAndReceive()` for those that you don't expect a reply, you'll use `convertAndSend()`. Of course you'll need a different post processor for each. Or, you can just use 2 different queues to make life simpler. Of course, the `JmsListener` that doesn't produce a reply should return `null` (or have a `void` return).

Comment: For the message you expect replies to, you will use `convertSendAndReceive()` for those that you don't expect a reply, you'll use `convertAndSend()`. Of course you'll need a different post processor for each. Or, you can just use 2 different queues to make life simpler. Of course, the `JmsListener` that doesn't produce a reply should return `null` (or have a `void` return). See my edit for an alternative to all this, if the listener knows from the data whether a reply is expected or not.

Comment: Yes; that is perfectly fine; you'll only get an error routing a reply (with no replyTo) if the method actually returns a result. If it returns `null`, that's the end of things.

Comment: OK, I was also considering two seperate queues, but am curious if I can use the selector.  Is this correct for jmsMessageTemplate ? MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message). setHeader("requiresReply", "false").build(); c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111770/discussion-between-stealth-rabbi-and-gary-russell).